# Change the email language

Tags: members

I think my question is very easy, but I can't find out how. I have changed the default language under Admin > General Configuration to "Dutch". But the e-mail that are send when a user registers or does a password recovery are all in English. The Dutch file `email_date.php` does contain the translation but this English is send.

How do I fix this? Of do I need to change another language setting?

Comment: Any progress on this that you can share?

Comment: @Paul, see the Answer that I marked as 'answer' from okenathan below. That's how I fixed my problem.

Comment: I see, your situation is a lot simpler since you're only using one language. We're using six. Hopefully unticking "Enable This Template" for the email notifications will do the trick since the docs aren't clear.

Comment: @Paul, indeed I only use one language and in that case this dirty fix can be used. In you situation it's a little different. I don't have any solution for that (also didn't look further since my issue was fixed). If you have a answer, I would like to hear it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the content of the emails (including the language) any way you like:

Log into the CP, goto Design --> message pages --> Email Notifications

Comment: Thank you, this will do it. But the strange thing is that although I've set the CP to Dutch, the English mail is send. But for now, I'm saved with this option!